# Derivative of $\sin(x)$ issues

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, derivatives, proof-explanation

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sin(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(x+h) - \sin(x)}{h}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sin(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)\cos(h) + \cos(x)\sin(h) - \sin(x)}{h}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sin(x) = \sin(x)\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\cos(h) -1}{h} + \cos(x)\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(h)}{h}$$

Normally I'd use L'Hopital's Rule here but considering that I'm trying to find the derivative in the first place, that kind of defeats the purpose.

Is there an easier way to approach these limits? I'm not seeing anything obvious.

Comment: This is pretty much the standard way to do it.

Comment: The derivative of $\sin(x)$ is what I am trying to prove in the first place, I am pretending I don't know the derivative is $\cos(x)$ going into it

Comment: Cheat and use the fact that for small $h$, $\sin h \approx h$ and $\cos h \approx 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Better to use [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)

$$\sin(x+h)-\sin x=2\sin(h/2)\cos(h/2+x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You can use the squeeze theorem to show that
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(h)}{h} = 1.$$
You can also show that
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\cos(h)-1}{h} = 0.$$
Try multiplying top and bottom by $\cos(h) + 1$. You will need to use the first limit.

Comment: I did consider this but wasn't able to get anywhere. For instance $-1 \leq \sin(h) \leq 1$ then $-1/h \leq \sin(h)/h \leq 1/h$ but I was still having a divide-by-$0$ issue with that so...

Comment: You can show that $\cos(x) < \sin(x)/x<1/\cos(x)$. For the other limit consider multiplying top and bottom by $\cos(h) +1$.

Comment: Ah clever use of squeeze theorem! For the other one though I am not sure. Multiplying the way you suggest gets me $(\cos(h)^2 - 1) / (h(\cos(h) + 1))$ and I don't know how to get rid of that $h$ on the bottom.

Comment: Although from the Pythagorean identity it's also equal to $-\sin(h)^2 / (h(\cos(h)+1))$... hmmm

Comment: I can rewrite as $-\frac{\frac{\sin(h)}{h} \sin(h)}{\cos(h)+1}$ which goes to I can rewrite as $-\frac{1 \cdot \sin(0)}{\cos(0)+1}$ or $-\frac{0}{2} = 0$. Is this a correct way to reach the result?

Comment: @user525966: yes that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is no algebraic approach to it. The two I know are:

- use some geometric considerations on the unit circle to obtain the two limits by squeezing with obvious limits.
- Define sine and cosine using their Taylor series. The derivatives are then obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos(h)-1}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos^2(\frac{h}{2})-\sin^2(\frac{h}{2})-\cos^2(\frac{h}{2})-\sin^2(\frac{h}{2})}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}(-\frac{h}{2}*\frac{\sin^2(\frac{h}{2})}{(\frac{h}{2})^2})=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Before studying derivatives you are supposed to be somewhat familiar with limits (and continuity) and when you study these topics you will encounter the following theorem (with or without proof) $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x} {x} =1\tag{1}$$ The [typical proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75151/72031) proceeds using the inequalities $$\sin x<x<\tan x$$ for $0<x<\pi/2$. An easy consequence of this is the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x} {x^2}=\frac{1}{2}\tag{2}$$ and you should be able to deduce $(2)$ from $(1)$ easily using trigonometric identities. Now use the above results to finish your derivation.